# PHP var into Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, random, var

I have this php var, and I want to send it to php, but this way I can't

```
<?php
    $nb = rand(1,68);
?>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery ( '#dwDB-main' ).fadeTo ( 1, 0.01 );
    function random() {
    $rd = <?php $nb ?>;
    return $rd;
    }
```

Comment: Well, $rd isn't how you define a variable in javascript; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: After all the fixes from other comments, your random() will still not return random number as you expected. It will always return the value it initially retrieved from PHP. You'd better use javascript Math.random() to really generate random number in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use echo for transfer the variable statement, actually its not able to print

```
<?php
$nb = rand(1,68);
?>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery ( '#dwDB-main' ).fadeTo ( 1, 0.01 );
    function random() {
        var $rd = <?php echo $nb; ?>;
        return $rd;
    }
```

Comment: `$rd = <?php echo $nb ?>;` are you sure this is correct?

Comment: an semicolon is needed for sperating the php statement

Comment: its $rd = <?php echo $nb; ?>;

Comment: No, `$rd` isn't how you define a variable in javascript

Comment: sorry i missed var

Answer (score 1):

```
function random() {
    var rd = <?= $nb ?>;
    return rd;
}
```

Comment: This is the same OP wrote, and doesn't even work...

Comment: should work now, I was still editing

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
    $nb = rand(1,68);
?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function random() {
    var rd = <?php echo $nb ?>;
        return rd;
    }
    console.log(random());
</script>
```

And remember if you are using jquery then please add jquery script also.